# CMake won't Link C library to C++ program

Tags: c++, c, cmake, dynamic-linking

Probably the shortest working example I can think of:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
project(myprogs)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_executable(myprog2 main.c)
add_executable(myprog main.cpp)
add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.c)

target_link_libraries(myprog2 mylib)
target_link_libraries(myprog mylib)
```

**main.c**/**main.cpp** (identical contents):

```
#include "mylib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  doit();
}
```

**mylib.h**:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

void doit(void);

#endif
```

**mylib.c**:

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(void)
{
  printf("doit");
}
```

**System:**

- Ubunto 15.10
- gcc 5.2.1/clang 3.6.2 (tried both)
- CMake 3.2.2

When I do a `make myprog`, `myprog`'s link phase complains that there is an undefined reference to `doit`. However, if I use `make myprog2`, everything links correctly and the program runs as expected.

I don't understand why CMake isn't properly linking to `mylib` correctly in the C++ program. Getting verbose output form the compiler gives (I've trimmed some of the linking to system library paths/object files):

> "/usr/bin/ld" -export-dynamic --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dyna
>   mic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o myprog CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/main.cpp.o **libmylib.so** -rpath /home/andrew/code/misc/myprog/build -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc

Strangely, it's not using a `-lmylib` to link with mylib. I get a similar output for `myprog2`.

My question is why is this happening, and more importantly, how do I get `myprog` to properly link to `mylib`?

Comment: It is not CMake that has the problem, but rather the linker. CMake does not do the linking

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to declare [c](/questions/tagged/c) functions with `extern "C"` in c++. The [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) compiler changes function names in order to allow function overloading, so for instance

```
int function(int value);
```

and

```
int function(char *value);
```

both can be defined in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) with exactly the same name, the compiler will generate two different functions with different names for this to work correctly.

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) you can't do this, and the function name will not need to be modified. By using `extern "C"` you prevent the compiler from altering function names, and so the link phase will work as you expect it.

To fix it, start main.cpp this way:

```
extern "C" {
#include "mylib.h"
}
```

Comment: hmm... this makes sense, but why don't I have to wrap system C libraries with `extern "C"` (or should I be and have been lucky so far?) For example, I searched the GTK+3.0 headers and there's not a single mention of `extern "C"` and I'm not doing this wrapping in my C++ codes.

Comment: @helloworld922 - it's because most include files already contain lines like `#ifdef __cplusplus`, `extern "C" {` and `#endif`.

Comment: Are you using *GTK-3.0* in c++ code? Or is it *gtkmm-3.0*?

Comment: It is not gtkmm-3.0, but GTK-3.0 (yeah, I probably should use gtkmm, but in the past I've run into problems where gtkmm lags behind feature-wise from gtk+)

Comment: @alvits As I said, I did a grep search of all the GTK+ headers and didn't find a single mention of `extern "C"` at all. I don't know where else the `extern "C"` could be hiding.

Comment: I just confirmed what you say and there are `extern "C"`'s, It's a macro called `G_BEGIN_DECLS` defiend in */usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h* which is simply `extern "C" {`, and of course has to be matched with a corresponding `G_END_DECLS`.

Comment: Hallelujah! This solved my problem after an hour of Googling!