# Symbols lost when compiling library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

On my cmake project I am trying to compile some parts of the following library:
https://github.com/Danixu/lz4ultra

It compiles the library just fine, but when It tries to link it to the main program it says that a reference doesn't exists. I am sure that I have added the correct file and the problem is related with something that maybe I have not configured correctly in the CMakeLists.txt file, because when I compile the library manually it compiles correctly.

The CMakeLists.txt I am using to compile that library is the following:

```
# Make an automatic library - will be static or dynamic based on user setting
add_library(lz4ultra
  ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/divsufsort.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/sssort.c 
  ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/trsort.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/dictionary.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/frame.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/matchfinder.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/shrink_block.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/shrink_context.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/shrink_inmem.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/stream.c
  ../lz4ultra/src/xxhash/xxhash.c
)

# We need this directory, and users of our library will need it too
target_include_directories(lz4ultra PUBLIC ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/include/)
```

The main program CMakeLists.txt file is the following:

```
add_executable(ziso ziso.cpp)

target_include_directories(ziso PUBLIC ../include/)
set_target_properties(ziso PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)

target_link_libraries(ziso PUBLIC stdc++ -static lz4ultra lz4)
```

And I am using this one to join all together:

```
# Works with 3.14 and tested through 3.27
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# Project name and a few useful settings. Other commands can pick up the results
project(
  Ziso
  VERSION 0.5.1
  DESCRIPTION "Another Ziso compressor with advanced features"
  LANGUAGES C CXX)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -s")

# Only do these if this is the main project, and not if it is included through add_subdirectory
if(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME STREQUAL PROJECT_NAME)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
  set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

  # The compiled LZ4 library code is here
  add_subdirectory(lib/lz4-cmake)

  # The compiled LZ4ultra library code is here
  add_subdirectory(lib/lz4ultra-cmake)

  # The executable code is here
  add_subdirectory(src)
endif()
```

but running the compile command just gives me an error saying that the symbol doesn't exists:

```
$ rm -rf CMakeFiles ; rm -rf */CMakeFiles ; rm -rf */*/CMakeFiles ; rm -rf */*/*/CMakeFiles && cmake --build .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MINGW64_NT-10.0-22621 to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
Your CMakeCache.txt file was copied to CopyOfCMakeCache.txt. Please post that file on discourse.cmake.org.
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MINGW64_NT-10.0-22621 to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /mingw64/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/MINGW64_NT-10.0-22621 to use this system, please post your config file on discourse.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /mingw64/bin/CC.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (2.5s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: /c/Users/Danixu/Mi unidad/_Proyectos/Programacion/C/ziso_compressor
[  5%] Building C object lib/lz4-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4.dir/__/lz4/lib/lz4.c.obj
[ 11%] Building C object lib/lz4-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4.dir/__/lz4/lib/lz4hc.c.obj
[ 17%] Linking C static library liblz4.a
[ 17%] Built target lz4
[ 23%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/divsufsort.c.obj
[ 29%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/sssort.c.obj
[ 35%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/trsort.c.obj
[ 41%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/dictionary.c.obj
[ 47%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/frame.c.obj
[ 52%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/matchfinder.c.obj
[ 58%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/shrink_block.c.obj
[ 64%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/shrink_context.c.obj
[ 70%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/shrink_inmem.c.obj
[ 76%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/stream.c.obj
[ 82%] Building C object lib/lz4ultra-cmake/CMakeFiles/lz4ultra.dir/__/lz4ultra/src/xxhash/xxhash.c.obj
[ 88%] Linking C static library liblz4ultra.a
[ 88%] Built target lz4ultra
[ 94%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/ziso.dir/ziso.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/ziso
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/ziso.dir/ziso.cpp.obj:ziso.cpp:(.text$_Z14compress_blockPKcjPcjRb3opt[_Z14compress_blockPKcjPcjRb3opt]+0x80): undefined reference to `lz4ultra_compress_inmem(unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned int, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ziso.dir/build.make:99: bin/ziso] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:187: src/CMakeFiles/ziso.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Compiling the file manually with the following commands generates a working library:

```
$ g++ -c -I ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/include/ ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/divsufsort.c ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/sssort.c  ../lz4ultra/src/libdivsufsort/lib/trsort.c ../lz4ultra/src/dictionary.c ../lz4ultra/src/frame.c ../lz4ultra/src/matchfinder.c ../lz4ultra/src/shrink_block.c ../lz4ultra/src/shrink_context.c ../lz4ultra/src/shrink_inmem.c ../lz4ultra/src/stream.c ../lz4ultra/src/xxhash/xxhash.c

$ ar rvs test.a *.o
```

I have even tried to add all the source C files to the main program but the error is not gone, so I think that maybe the problem is related with the compilation arguments used when generated by cmake.

NOTE: I am using MSYS2 on Windows and I am compiling using MinGW64. I have also checked the function with nm.

I suspect that maybe the problem is that cmake is optimizing the code using the O3 argument, but I am not able to remove it.

EDIT: The problem seems to be because is merging C and C++. What I don't understand is why this has not happened when I have merged the LZ4 library which is C, with the C++ program.

The nm output:

```
$ nm lib/lz4ultra-cmake/liblz4ultra.a

divsufsort.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000090 T divsufsort_build_array
0000000000000000 T divsufsort_destroy
0000000000000040 T divsufsort_init
                 U free
                 U malloc
                 U memset
                 U sssort
                 U trsort

sssort.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000400 r lg_table
0000000000000000 r sqq_table
0000000000000000 t ss_mintrosort
0000000000001700 t ss_swapmerge
0000000000002910 T sssort

trsort.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 r lg_table
0000000000000000 t tr_introsort.constprop.0
00000000000023a0 T trsort

dictionary.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U __imp__ftelli64
                 U fclose
                 U fopen
                 U fread
                 U free
                 U fseek
0000000000000100 T lz4ultra_dictionary_free
0000000000000000 T lz4ultra_dictionary_load
                 U malloc

frame.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U XXH32
0000000000000140 T lz4ultra_check_header
0000000000000280 T lz4ultra_decode_frame
00000000000001a0 T lz4ultra_decode_header
0000000000000080 T lz4ultra_encode_compressed_block_frame
0000000000000110 T lz4ultra_encode_footer_frame
0000000000000000 T lz4ultra_encode_header
00000000000000a0 T lz4ultra_encode_uncompressed_block_frame

matchfinder.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U divsufsort_build_array
0000000000000160 T lz4ultra_build_suffix_array
0000000000000700 T lz4ultra_find_all_matches
0000000000000000 t lz4ultra_find_matches_at.isra.0
00000000000006b0 T lz4ultra_skip_matches

shrink_block.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 T lz4ultra_optimize_and_write_block
                 U memcmp
                 U memcpy

shrink_context.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U divsufsort_destroy
                 U divsufsort_init
                 U free
                 U lz4ultra_build_suffix_array
0000000000000100 T lz4ultra_compressor_destroy
0000000000000220 T lz4ultra_compressor_get_command_count
0000000000000000 T lz4ultra_compressor_init
0000000000000170 T lz4ultra_compressor_shrink_block
                 U lz4ultra_find_all_matches
                 U lz4ultra_optimize_and_write_block
                 U lz4ultra_skip_matches
                 U malloc

shrink_inmem.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000080 T lz4ultra_compress_inmem
                 U lz4ultra_compressor_destroy
                 U lz4ultra_compressor_init
                 U lz4ultra_compressor_shrink_block
                 U lz4ultra_encode_compressed_block_frame
                 U lz4ultra_encode_footer_frame
                 U lz4ultra_encode_header
                 U lz4ultra_encode_uncompressed_block_frame
0000000000000000 T lz4ultra_get_max_compressed_size_inmem
                 U memcpy

stream.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U fclose
                 U feof
                 U fopen
                 U fread
                 U fwrite
0000000000000000 t lz4ultra_filestream_close
0000000000000030 t lz4ultra_filestream_eof
0000000000000080 T lz4ultra_filestream_open
0000000000000060 t lz4ultra_filestream_read
0000000000000040 t lz4ultra_filestream_write

xxhash.c.obj:
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
00000000000008d0 T XXH32
0000000000001080 T XXH32_canonicalFromHash
0000000000000ba0 T XXH32_copyState
0000000000000b80 T XXH32_createState
0000000000000e60 T XXH32_digest
0000000000000b90 T XXH32_freeState
0000000000001090 T XXH32_hashFromCanonical
0000000000000bd0 T XXH32_reset
0000000000000c20 T XXH32_update
00000000000010a0 T XXH64
0000000000001630 T XXH64_canonicalFromHash
0000000000001260 T XXH64_copyState
0000000000001240 T XXH64_createState
0000000000001540 T XXH64_digest
0000000000000000 t XXH64_finalize.constprop.0
0000000000001250 T XXH64_freeState
0000000000001640 T XXH64_hashFromCanonical
00000000000012a0 T XXH64_reset
0000000000001330 T XXH64_update
00000000000008c0 T XXH_versionNumber
                 U free
                 U malloc
                 U memcpy
```

Comment: use `nm` to see if you can find the function in the library, and if you do, make sure both sides agree on stuff like calling convention and name mangling

Comment: Hello, yes, I forgot to say that I have also tried the nm command and the function is there, but looks like is what you say, because for testing I have changed the "C" compiler to "g++" instead "gcc" and now compiles... maybe my other tests were wrong because I though that was working with gcc too. I'd like to investigate a bit more because I don't understand why the lz4 library is linked correctly even when it is compiled by gcc, and this one fails.

Comment: The linker's looking for `lz4ultra_compress_inmem(unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned int, int)` How does this match what you found with `nm`? Add the relevant `nm` output to the question because the answer likely will be in the difference between the two, and there are people here who can explain what happened and almost certainly how to beat CMake into producing the output you need.

Comment: done, the function is on the `shrink_inmem.c.obj` file.

Comment: Groovy.  Now until I can remember what the `T` in `0000000000000080 T lz4ultra_compress_inmem` stands for I should probably step back and let the experts go. Check the `nm` man page for more options. See if you can get it to print out the arguments `lz4ultra_compress_inmem` expects. I think you get that info with `nm -C`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the problem thanks in part to user4581301 which has pointed me in the right direction.

As he/she said, the problem was related with the name convention because the differences in the C++ and C compilation.

To solve it I just have added `extern "C"` to the header files and now it compiles as expected.

```
extern "C"
{
#include "../lib/lz4ultra/src/format.h"
#include "../lib/lz4ultra/src/shrink_inmem.h"
}
```

The answer was found here: [CMake won't Link C library to C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408095/cmake-wont-link-c-library-to-c-program)

Something new to learn...

Best regards.

Comment: Hah! Missed this coming in. Be careful when making an answer that effectively repeats another answer. When you write an answer like that, you're usually better off proposing a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, I see... I didn't know about that (I usually don't use the close button), but I have proposed it as duplicate ;)